# How can an imported graphic be deleted?

Tags: eaglecad

I imported a graphic into Eagle, and what it did was make a ton of little tiny lines to get the image.  I want to now delete all of that. I tried selecting the group, and then using the `DELETE` command. How can I delete this stuff?

Comment: Have you tried undo . CTRL + Z in windows. While you still in the same session. Closing and reopening the editor will wipe the undo.. :(

Comment: Undo wouldn't work.  The image had already been placed a while back, and now it needs to be removed.

Comment: Undo actually doesn't work on that anyway. I always save right before I run a ulp and then don't save again until I've verified that the result of the ulp was exactly what I want. Alternatively Eagle keeps a history of 10 I believe. Look in your folder for files like NAMEOFBOARD.b#1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here is how to delete a group:**

To select the whole graphic and move it/delete it etc you use the group cmd to highlight all the mini-rectangles it makes, then select your tool (move,delete etc.) and then CTRL+right-click to execute that tool on the whole group.

**Here is an additional tip on working with bitmaps in Eagle:**

The import-bmp.ulp automatically puts your graphic at the origin. So before I run it I generally move my entire board away from the origin so that I can cleanly select the graphic group after importing it.

If you end up moving it in the middle of your board and then decide you don't like it, you can hide all layers except for the layer you put the graphic on and then the group command won't grab a bunch of stuff you don't want it to.

Comment: Perfect, the CTRL-right-click did the trick. Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!